# unresolved reference bundle android studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I just started to learning kotlin for android studio and built my first project, i did not touched anything but android studio getting me this error:
unresolved reference bundle, even trying to import android.os.Bundle did not worked.
at first i was getting the error :
unresolved reference R, but when i updated kotlin plugin, getting previous error that i already told you about.
as i said i never touched anything and this files built by android studio itself.
any ideas ?

this is app level gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deathstroke.samplekotlinproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and this is project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is main activity class :

```
package com.example.deathstroke.samplekotlinproject

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.bundle;

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

android studio showing me Bunlde in red color and alt + Enter dose not have an option as import class...

Answer (score 1):

Class names in Kotlin are case sensitive. So you have to import `Bundle` instead of `bundle`

```
import android.os.Bundle
```

Comment: There is no such class named Bundle in android.os suggestion list. cause if there was any, Alt +Enter would import that for me.

Comment: It's strange because Android framework definitely has this class. Maybe you have to invalidate AS cache. You can do it by `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: already tried that but did not work either, so i had to update android studio to version 3.5.0 and Kotlin to 1.3.50, and everything is just fine for now, tanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 1):

Yours imports in **java code  but your methods in kotlin**

Remove your imports

```
  import android.os.bundle;
```

then replace

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

press **Alt+Enter** imports will included automatically in android studio.

```
import android.os.Bundle
```

Then clean and rebuild project